# Getting closest coordinates closest to point in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have one point (hereafter referred to as the original point) on a grid, say for example, `[3, 3]`.

I also have a set of points that are in the same horizontal and vertical lines as the original point, say, `[[3,1],[3,2],[3,4],[7,3],[8,3]]`.

I want some function that will return an array of at most four points: the points closest to the original point in each direction (i.e. left, right, above, below). With the example above, it would return,

```
[[3,2],[3,4],[7,3]]
```

because `[3,2]` is the closest point on the left, `[3,4]` is the closest point on the right, `[7,3]` is the closest point above, and there are no points below. (Order of direction is not important.)

Is there an elegant and reasonably concise way to do this, using Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: Wouldn't [3,1] be the closest point above?

Comment: No, [3,2] is closer to [3,3] than [3,1].

Comment: Is the input always sorted as in your example?

Comment: @rahulmohan I didn't want to count on it, but it actually will because it is generated by a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know JavaScript, but the following algorithm would be very simple, if you can formulate it with JavaScript.

Let `(X0, Y0)` be the original point.

Iterate through the array, `[(X1, Y1), ..., (XN, YN)]`, and keep account of the minimum values of

R = Xi - X0 > 0

and

L = X0 - Xi > 0

as you proceed. 
At the end of the iteration  these values give you the closest points, i.e., `X0 + R` 
and `X0 - L`.

Do a similar iteration on the vertical line of points.